# How to get the img src using Nokogiri and at_css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the `src` value of a block of HTML. I am specifically trying to achieve this using the `at_css` and not using XPath.

So far all I'm getting is either nil or a blank string.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="" id="imageProductContainer">
  <a id="idLinkProductMainImage" href='URL'>
    <img id="productMainImage" src="SRC.jpg" alt="alt" title="A Title" align="left" class="product_image_productpage_main selectorgadget_selected">
  </a>  
</div>
```

The code I have is:

```
item = page.doc.at_css("#productMainImage img").text.strip unless page.doc.at_css("#productMainImage img").nil?

puts item #prints blank
item = item["src"]
puts item #prints blank
```

Where `page.doc` is the Nokogiri HTML element.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you need the `src` attribute, you can do it like this:

```
pace.doc.at_css('#idLinkProductMainImage img').attr('src')
```

Also, I believe the problem is the way you are getting the `img` tag. You are trying to get all `img` tags inside `#productMainImage`, but this `id` is the image itself, so it will find nothing.

If you use the link id `#idLinkProductMainImage`, then you have a `img` tag to search inside it.